# TF Listener error when running two kinects with openni_launch

Tags: kinect, pcl, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm trying to achieve something simple:

- launch 2 kinects
- publish static TF between kinects and HRIworkspace frames
- merge the 2 pointclouds in HRIworkspace
- run octomaps for later moveit planning. This is the fundamental issue: Octomaps cannot take as input multiple Pointcloud: it works only with 1 pointcloud. So I need to rotate and merge my individual pointcloud so that i can fill the result into octomap...

My issue is that I have it running with one kinect. but "just" running a second node of kinect breaks something and listener->waitForTransform  throws me the typical error: [ERROR] [1408981523.817028455]: "HRIworkspace" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.

Import thing: I know that I can have only 1 Kinect per Hub. And I did pay attention to this.

so, Step by step:

Step 1. Kinect Launch files. Launches both kinects and the static publishers for the kinects links.

```
<!-- Parameters possible to change-->
<arg name="camera1_id" default="1@0" />
<arg name="camera2_id" default="2@0" />
<arg name="depth_registration" default="true" />

<!-- Default parameters-->
<arg name="camera1_name" default="kinect1" />
<arg name="camera2_name" default="kinect2" />
   
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="world_to_HRIworkspace" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /world /HRIworkspace 10" /> 

<!-- Launching first kinect-->
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
  <arg name="device_id" value="$(arg camera1_id)" />
  <arg name="camera" value="$(arg camera1_name)" />
  <arg name="depth_registration" value="$(arg depth_registration)" />
  <arg name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
</include>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="HRIworkspace_to_kinect1_link"  args="2 -2 2 2.356 0.35 0 /HRIworkspace /kinect1_link 1" /> 

<!-- Launching second kinect-->
<include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
  <arg name="device_id" value="$(arg camera2_id)" />
  <arg name="camera" value="$(arg camera2_name)" />
  <arg name="depth_registration" value="$(arg depth_registration)" />
  <arg name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
</include>

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="HRIworkspace_to_kinect2_link" args="2 2 2 -2.356 0.35 0 /HRIworkspace /kinect2_link 1" />
```

Step 2. The future merging node, with the tf listner.

Ok, for debug purposes, it doesn't do much of merging... but I need this to run before implementing more.
Now it only tries to get the transform and transform the pointcloud...

Note that the definition of the tf: listener is the main, so its buffer should have time to fill...

```
void cloud_cb1(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input1) {
       listener->waitForTransform("kinect1_rgb_optical_frame","HRIworkspace", (*input1).header.stamp, ros::Duration(10.0) );
       pcl_ros::transformPointCloud("HRIworkspace",*input1, output1, *listener);
       pub.publish(output);    
    }

    int main (int argc, char** argv)
    {
    // Initialize ROS
    ros::init (argc, argv, "merge2pcl2");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    listener = new tf::TransformListener();
    ros::Subscriber sub1 = nh.subscribe ("/kinect1/depth_registered/points", 1, cloud_cb1);
    pub = nh.advertise ("output", 1);
    ros::spin ();
    }
```

Step3: If i run only 1 kinect:

No problem all TF transforms are found, code running smoothly, republishing the pointcloud.
TF echo runs ok
rosrun tf tf_monitor kinect1_rgb_optical_frame HRIworkspace  runs ok

```
RESULTS: for kinect1_rgb_optical_frame to HRIworkspace
Chain is: HRIworkspace -> world -> kinect1_link -> kinect1_rgb_frame -> kinect1_link -> kinect1_depth_frame
Net delay     avg = -0.000275143: max = 0.000302901

Frames:

All Broadcasters:
Node: /HRIworkspace_to_kinect1_link 930.502 Hz, Average Delay: -0.000832957 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect1_base_link 10.2617 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0998126 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect1_base_link1 10.2613 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0998158 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect1_base_link2 10.2616 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0998104 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect1_base_link3 10.2616 Hz, Average Delay: -0.099813 Max Delay: 0
Node: /world_to_HRIworkspace 99.4637 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00981339 Max Delay: 0
```

Step4: I run the 2 kinects.
-> The two poincloud are well seen in rviz. and the TF correclty applies the transformation in rviz.

-> I have the following error, EVEN if I don't publish the static TF for the second kinect.
[ERROR] [1408986109.067499370]: "HRIworkspace" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.

-> The TF frames are correctly set: http://postimg.org/image/5ckc5r3tx/

-> tf_monitor shows:

```
RESULTS: for kinect1_rgb_optical_frame to HRIworkspace
Chain is: HRIworkspace -> world -> HRIworkspace -> kinect2_link -> kinect1_depth_frame -> kinect1_link -> kinect2_depth_frame -> kinect1_rgb_frame -> kinect1_link -> kinect2_link -> kinect2_rgb_frame
Net delay     avg = 0.00458208: max = 0.095311

Frames:

All Broadcasters:
Node: /HRIworkspace_to_kinect1_link 931.587 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0008456 Max Delay: 0.000991727
Node: /HRIworkspace_to_kinect2_link 931.519 Hz, Average Delay: -0.000847671 Max Delay: 0.000784096
Node: /kinect1_base_link 10.0039 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0998451 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect1_base_link1 10.0039 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0998217 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect1_base_link2 10.0039 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0998242 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect1_base_link3 10.0038 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0998209 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect2_base_link 10.004 Hz, Average Delay: -0.099828 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect2_base_link1 10.004 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0998313 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect2_base_link2 10.0038 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0998222 Max Delay: 0
Node: /kinect2_base_link3 10.0039 Hz, Average Delay: -0.099828 Max Delay: 0
Node: /world_to_HRIworkspace 99.2859 Hz, Average Delay: -0.00982809 Max Delay: 0
```

---

***SO, my conclusions up to now:***

- The chain found by tf_monitor seems quite strange and not as direct as i would have thought.
- The delay of doesn't seem to be an issue!... Does it??

I'm quite lost now, having looked at all the questions and tutorials I could find...
Really need help here...

Any idea about how to solve this issue?

Anything to do with nodelets? (I don't control this aspect at all...)

Thanks in advance.

Damien

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191197/tf-listener-error-when-running-two-kinects-with-openni_launch/) by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2014-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem is your assumption that because `listener` is in the main, the buffer should have time to fill (assumptions are always a bit risky ;-).
Another issue is that `waitForTransform()` will timeout upon failure and you are not checking whether it returned `true` or `false`.

Thus, I think you can solve your problem by replacing the `waitForTransform()` with:

```
if listener->canTransform(...) {
    pcl::transformPointCloud(...);
    pub.publish(output);
}
else {
    ROS_WARN("cannot transform from ... to ...");
}
```

If you really want to use the `waitForTransform()` and can afford to wait, do not pass a time as timeout.

If you want to use `waitForTransform()` with the timeout, make sure you check whether the timeout occurred and do not try to transform the point cloud and publish if it did timeout.

Regarding the way `tf_monitor` shows the chain, I have yet to understand that too. It appears it goes all the way up to the root, then traverses down to the desired frame, ignoring shorter paths.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Damien](https://answers.ros.org/users/2349/damien/) on 2014-09-01**:
Thanks.I was printing the bool in the console to check if the TF exists.
The issue at the end is that with 1 kinect the code works nice and rotates correctly the pointcloud.
But when I launch the second kinect node, NO TF is found...
Might it come from the nodelets?
Where should I start looking?